# Redefine \big, \Big, etc. dimension locally

Tags: macros

I'd like to redefine `\big`, `\Big` etc. commands to change their dimensions for single equations. E.g.

```latex
{\makeatletter\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@{2}}\makeatother%
\begin{equation}
\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)
\end{equation}}\relax
```

For practical reasons I'd like to define, in the preamble, a command like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\mybig}[1]{\makeatletter\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@{#1}}\makeatother}
```

so to have something like:

```latex
{\mybig{2}%
\begin{equation}
\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)
\end{equation}}\relax
```

But it doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `\makeatletter/other` must always be outside the macro definition. Use `\makeatletter\newcommand{\mybig}[1]{\renewcommand{\big}{\bBigg@{#1}}}\makeatother`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, Yes it does! If you post an answer to my question I will accept it.

Comment: Sorry, the question got closed before I got to write an answer. But the answer in the linked duplicate describes exactly why your attempt didn't work (it's a fairly common mistake, I myself made it a few times ;-)