# Use \makeatletter \@hello \makeatother in footnote

Tags: macros, footnotes, texmaker

I have an issue with a new command I use, to create a new template for a workgroup.

In my main document, I create a new commant like below, to allow my users to define a new word I will put in the front page of their report. I do so, because I don't want them to mess up the huge amount of code in the frontpage.

```
% create the new command
\makeatletter
\newcommand\hello[1]{\def\@hello{#1}}
\makeatother

% later one, they use this
\hello{hello world}
```

In my front page document, this is called in a footnote like below :

```
\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{{ 
\makeatletter
\@hello
\makeatother
}
```

The result of this (via pdflatex in texmaker) is that there is `hello` wrote in the footnote instead of `hello world`. Note, when I put the `\makeatletter\@hello\makeatother` in the main text, it works.

Do I have to define the full footnote in my new command ?

Thx in advance

Comment: `\makeatletter/other` must always be _outside_ the command definition or macro call (in your case the `\footnote` call). You have to use `\makeatletter \footnote{\@hello} \makeatother`. See here and the linked duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/526818/134574

Comment: Okay thanks it works now!

Comment: Great! I marked a duplicate, of your question, for future readers to have more context. By the way, welcome to TeX.SX!